# In oracle i have this Dataype: "VARCHAR2(255 Byte)" what would be the converted/mapping Dataype in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, sqldatatypes, varchar2

In Oracle I have this  Dataype: `VARCHAR2(255 Byte)`  what would be the converted/mapping  Dataype in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql, Oracle's `VARCHAR2` will map to `VARCHAR`.

You can check other data types here:
https://www.convert-in.com/docs/ora2pgs/types-mapping.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mapping Oracle datatypes to PostgreSQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/mapping-oracle-datatypes-to-postgresql/), you can pick one of

- char,
- varchar,
- text,
- json

I'd try with `varchar(255)`

Answer (score 0):

The best match is `varchar(255)`.

But it's not 100% identical because it matches Oracle's `varchar(255 char)`.

There is no way to limit the size of a column based on bytes in Postgres - only characters (which is a different thing for a multi-byte character set).

Note that neither in Postgres nor in Oracle the "magic number" 255 opens up any storage or memory optimizations compared to e.g. 256 or 275.